# error Process ForkPoolWorker-X: when using multiprecessing connecting to IP routers

Tags: python, networking, automation, ip, router

I use python script to audit a CPE device by hundreds somtimes thousands, I use parallel function to connect to routers simultaneously I have sometimes this error:
Process ForkPoolWorker-X:
for your information I use parallel this way :
results = Parallel(n_jobs=30, backend="multiprocessing")(delayed(main_process)(ip, dossier_test) for ip in block)
the problem is when I run the script on one or two IP it's OK but I do it for big ranges (but still with maximum of 30 at the same time) I had this notification that stops the execution of the script.
the other probleme is that the SIGALARM is not working every time which is supposed to make script on running until the end.
def timeout_handler(signum, frame):
raise TimeoutError("Le temps d'execution est ecoule")
signal.signal(signal.SIGALRM, timeout_handler)

thank you for your help I hope it's clear.

I tried to print all the important steps of my code so I can see the root cause of the problem but seen nothing suspicious. I am expecting to have my script working until the end.